# Selecionar todos os Filhos, exceto o Primeiro com o css

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Queria inserir algumas propriedades nas divs de classe "content", porém queria que essas propriedades ignorassem o primeiro filho, como a margem por exemplo. Gostaria que todos tivessem uma distância de 20px uma da outra, mas se aplico diretamente a classe "content", o primeiro filho também espaça 20px do topo do browser e não quero que o fato ocorra. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Uma sugestão. Se quiser aplicar uma margem entre os elementos e não quer aplicar esta margem ao topo, você pode usar a propriedade do css `margin-bottom`.

Comment: Mas assim o último filho também pegaria o margin-bottom. E, dependendo do caso, às vezes essa margem inferior pode não ser necessária. Mas mesmo assim obrigado pela sugestão!

Comment: Ai quando você precisa definir mais regras o ideal é utilizar os seletores que o @hugocsl mencionou :)

Answer (score 5):

Existem algumas abordagens diferentes para isso, a que mais tem me agradado é com o `:not()` para fazer a exclusão do `first-child`

```css
.content:not(:first-child) {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="content">item </div>
    <div class="content">item </div>
    <div class="content">item </div>
    <div class="content">item </div>
    <div class="content">item </div>
</div>
```

**OBS:** Se você não quiser pegar nem o primeiro nem o último filho você pode concatenar mais de um `:not()` tipo `.content:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)`

*Suporte dos browsers*: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3